# is there a better way to write the property in OC?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have property like this:`@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGRect frame;`in the example.h file,i think this statement is to tell other class that the frame property is readonly and it also tell the compiler do not need to synthesize a setter method.
is that right to say that the class itself can use the instance variable _frame(the self.frame still can not use) in the .m file? if so,is there a better way to use this instance variable _frame? redeclare this property to readwrite in the class extension or redeclare the instance variable in class extension like this(i have found many guys write like this,but i do not understand what is the benefit of doing so?):

```
@interface example () {
    CGRect _frame;
}
@end

@implementation example
```

or i just need do nothing?

Comment: [Should I Use a Property or an Instance Variable?](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/should-i-use-a-property-or-an-instance-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about property as follows:
1.program find name of property in class of receiver when you take dot operator(.).
  Like this:   tt.frame   (example* tt = [[example alloc] init];)

2.Then program find relationship between name of property(binding with synthesized method same name as name of property) and instance variable. 
  The way for that is:    @synthesize frame=_frame;
  (frame is name of property,_frame is instance variable. Binding name of property and instance variable.If you don't do like this,compiler will provide a instance variable (frame,then modify this frame, not _frame you designed.)when you choice 64-bit environment.Or compiler will give you a warning, if you choice 32-bit environment)

3.Call method for the real instance variable.

Comment: i just do not understand the compiler already provide a instance variable for me, why should i write the instance variable again by myself in the class extension?